# Evaluate $ \lim_{ x \to 0, y \to 0}\frac{x^2+y^2+x+y}{x+y}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

How do you find $$\lim \limits_{x \to 0 , y\to 0}\frac{x^2+y^2+x+y}{x+y}$$or prove that it doesn't exist?

I've tried every method I know, but I can't find anything conclusive.

Comment: What happens if $x=-y$?

Comment: Hint: look at the limits as $y\to -x$ from above and below.

Comment: Isn't the function undefined if you do that?

Comment: @Bob: Only if you approach **on** that line. See my answer for a way to approach closer and closer to that line without actually hitting it.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Obviously the function isn’t defined along the line $y=-x$, so you might ask what happens when you approach the origin on a trajectory that approaches that line as $x\to 0$, like $$y=-x+x^2\;,$$ and compare with what happens when you approach along an axis. You can also simplify matters a little by noticing that

$$\frac{x^2+y^2+x+y}{x+y}=1+\frac{x^2+y^2}{x+y}\;,$$

so that you really need only look at

$$\lim_{\langle x,y\rangle\to\langle 0,0\rangle}\frac{x^2+y^2}{x+y}\;.$$